# Msg 116, Level 16, State 1

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Please help me how to fixed this issue

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure openclosebycat, Line 18
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is
>   not introduced with EXISTS.
>
> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure openclosebycat, Line 20
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

My code:

```
select distinct
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM dbo.PROBS 
     WHERE (STATUS LIKE 'closed')
       AND (OPEN_TIME >= @DateFrom)
       AND (CLOSE_TIME <= @DateTo)) AS closen,
   (SELECT NUMBER, STATUS, ID 
    FROM dbo.PROBS 
    WHERE (STATUS LIKE 'closed')
      AND (OPEN_TIME >= @DateFrom)
      AND (CLOSE_TIME <= @DateTo)) AS closedet,
  (SELECT NUMBER, STATUS, ID 
   FROM dbo.PROBS 
   WHERE (STATUS LIKE 'open')
     AND (OPEN_TIME >= @DateFrom)
     AND (CLOSE_TIME <= @DateTo)) AS opendet,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)  
   FROM dbo.PROBS
   WHERE (STATUS = 'closed') 
     AND (CATEGORY = 'problem') 
     AND (OPEN_TIME >= @DateFrom)
     AND (CLOSE_TIME <= @DateTo)) AS closeporb,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM dbo.PROBS
  WHERE (STATUS = 'closed') 
    AND (CATEGORY = 'request for information') 
    AND (OPEN_TIME >= @DateFrom)
    AND (CLOSE_TIME <= @DateTo)) AS closereinfo,
 (SELECT COUNT(*)  
  FROM dbo.PROBS 
  WHERE (STATUS = 'closed') 
    AND (CATEGORY = 'incident') 
    AND (OPEN_TIME >= @DateFrom) 
    AND (CLOSE_TIME <= @DateTo)) AS closeincid,
 (SELECT COUNT(*)  
  FROM dbo.PROBS 
  WHERE (STATUS = 'closed') 
    AND (CATEGORY = 'complaint') 
    AND (OPEN_TIME >= @DateFrom) 
    AND (CLOSE_TIME <= @DateTo)) AS closecomp,
 (SELECT COUNT(*)  
  FROM dbo.PROBS 
  WHERE (STATUS = 'open') 
    AND (CATEGORY = 'problem') 
    AND (OPEN_TIME >= @DateFrom)
    AND (CLOSE_TIME <= @DateTo)) AS openporb,
 (SELECT COUNT(*)  
  FROM dbo.PROBS 
  WHERE (STATUS = 'open') 
    AND (CATEGORY = 'request for information') 
    AND (OPEN_TIME >= @DateFrom)
    AND (CLOSE_TIME <= @DateTo)) AS openreinfo,
 (SELECT COUNT(*)  
  FROM dbo.PROBS 
  WHERE (STATUS = 'open') 
    AND (CATEGORY = 'incident') 
    AND (OPEN_TIME >= @DateFrom)
    AND (CLOSE_TIME <= @DateTo)) AS openincid,
 (SELECT COUNT(*)  
  FROM dbo.PROBS 
  WHERE (STATUS = 'open') 
    AND (CATEGORY = 'complaint') 
    AND (OPEN_TIME >= @DateFrom) 
    AND (CLOSE_TIME <= @DateTo)) AS opencomp,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM dbo.PROBS 
  WHERE (STATUS LIKE 'open')
    AND (OPEN_TIME >= @DateFrom)
    AND (CLOSE_TIME <= @DateTo)) AS openn
FROM
    dbo.PROBS
```

Comment: Looks like you have procedure `openclosebycat` which isn't fully pasted to a question and problem is related withh `EXISTS` keyword which is also missing.

Comment: You definately need to replace all of this code with the relevant CASE statement. There's no reason to do all of these sub queries in the select statement. The particular issue here is that each of your sub selects can only return one result, some are returning 3 (NUMBER, STATUS, ID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subquery in the `SELECT` can only select one attribute. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you'll have to re-write to something like:

```
SELECT   NUMBER
,        STATUS
,        ID
,        SUM(CASE 
                  WHEN STATUS like 'closed' and OPEN_TIME >= @DateFrom and CLOSE_TIME <= @DateTo 
                     THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0 
             END) as closen
,        {same for the other counts}
FROM     dbo.PROBS
GROUP BY NUMBER
,        STATUS
,        ID
```